# CodeIgniter Project showing Error when uploaded online server

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iU4Y.png)

.httaccess code here:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

my project is working good on local host but when i upload project on hosting server it shows error. error is mentioned in picture.
i attached my .htacces file above please guide.

Comment: did you change `$config['base_url']` and `$config['index_page']` in `application/config/config.php` to match your hosting settings?

Comment: yes. i had change these settings:

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://151.106.5.234/';

Comment: $config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: Friderich Weber please help

Comment: I just looked at the site. try `base_url['http://151.106.5.234'];`.  I'm unable to get to the controller even working around htaccess.  Where's your controller?  `application/controllers/Client.php` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

.httaccess like bellow:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

and set config.php like bellow code :

```
//$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) &&       $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```